# Deleting songs from playlist

Tags: android, playlist

I am trying to delete a song from playlist . But don't know why it is not deleting . These are the values I am checking in the debug mode: 
URI -- content://media/external/audio/playlists/4599/members
WHERE --audio_id=?
selectionArgs[]-- [1214]

I found while debugging that the control skips these lines in ContentResolver.class .

```
public final int delete(Uri url, String where, String[] selectionArgs)
{

    try {
        long startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis(); //skipped
        int rowsDeleted = provider.delete(mPackageName, url, where, selectionArgs);//skipped
        long durationMillis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;//skipped
        maybeLogUpdateToEventLog(durationMillis, url, "delete", where);
        return rowsDeleted;  // returns 0
    }
```

Posting below my code to delete song:

```
    public int deletePlaylistTracks(Context context, long playlistId,
        long audioId) {
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    int countDel = 0;
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri("external",
            playlistId);
            String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.AUDIO_ID
                + "=?";
        String selectionargs[] = { String.valueOf(audioId) };

        if (resolver.delete(uri, selection, selectionargs) != 0) {

        countDel++;
    }

    Log.d("TAG", "tracks deleted=" + countDel);
    return countDel;}  //returns 0
```

**UPDATE:**
This is how I am calling deletePlaylistTracks

```
public void delete(final List<Long> songsDelete, //audioId
        final List<Integer> position)
{
 if (playlistId != -1) {
 for (int i = 0; i < songsDelete.size(); i++) {
 Log.d("song going to del", ""+ songsDelete.get(i)); //audio Id 1214
 int countDel =   utility.deletePlaylistTracks(PlaylistTracks.this,playlistId,songsDelete.get(i));

}
```

Can anyone please suggest what could be wrong?

Comment: resolver.delete(uri,null,null) works fine in deleting all the songs. What could be the issue in audio Id then.

Comment: What was the used value of audioId? And why did it display as 'audio_id=?' ? And if the third argument was null why does that display as [1214]? Maybe you have to change + " = " + by + "=" +.

Comment: Dont get it. You gave it "=?" so it will show that. Why becomes valueOf(1) [1214] ?

Comment: I am sorry the updated code is the one which I debugged and posted the values. And I have no clue why it was displayed as audio_id :(.

Comment: That WHERE displayed as audio_id=? is very clear. But why does valueOf(audioId) display as [1214] when audioId==1 ?

Comment: Sorry if I am confusing you . Can you please point out what's the mistake in the updated code? The value of(1) [1214] is the audioId. Please ignore the audioId==1 . It was taken in another debug session.

Comment: Then adapt your post first. This will confuse others also. Show your call to deletePlaylistTracks with the used values for the parameters.

Comment: The updated code is the one matching correctly to the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the correct code.Hope it helps someone :)

```
public int deletePlaylistTracks(Context context, long playlistId,
        long audioId) {
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    int countDel = 0;
    try {
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members.getContentUri(
                "external", playlistId);
        String where = MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.Members._ID + "=?" ; // my mistake was I used .AUDIO_ID here

        String audioId1 = Long.toString(audioId);
        String[] whereVal = { audioId1 };
        countDel=resolver.delete(uri, where,whereVal);      
        Log.d("TAG", "tracks deleted=" + countDel);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return countDel;

 }
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me too. Sure it worked for you? ID of Song and my playlistID are correct

Comment: Yes it did work for me.Debug resolver.delete statement to see if the audioId value is going correctly or not.